# Create Grid of Dots in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, draw

WI wrote the following Beamer Code,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{C}
   \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
   
   \draw[brown] (-2,0.4) -- (2,0.4);
   \draw[-] (-4.5,0)--(4.5,0);
   \foreach \x/\name in {-4/$t_{1}$,-3/$t_{2}$,3/$t_{K-1}$,4/$t_{K}$}{
            \path[draw, fill=brown] (\x,0) circle[radius=2pt] node [above=2 mm, brown] {\name};
        }

 \end{tikzpicture} 
  \end{center}
   \end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to transform the brown line (above the black line) into a grid of dots??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add 'dotted' to draw `\draw[brown, dotted] (-2,0.4) -- (2,0.4);`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! (+1)